# Отмена/применение полей для поиска при постбеке

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Вот есть форма с WebGrid и полями поиска. Соответственно, при каждой отправке формы, на сервер приходят данные с этих полей. Ситуация: юзер пишет в поле слово "котики", жмет кнопку "серч" - все ок, приходят котики. Теперь юзер пишет в это поле "собачки", но кнопку серч не жмет, а, допустим жмет совсем другую кнопку, которая сабмитит форму, в итоге поиск таки выполняется по собачкам. Как выйти из положения? В виду достаточно странной архитектуры, контроллы на сервере почти ничего не знают друг о друге (нажатие кнопки серч отловить можно).

Comment: приведите больше подробностей, примеры кода и тк далее. Абстрактное описание про котиков и собачек мало о чем говорит. 

скажем, вот это выглядит весьма неочевидно: 

> Теперь юзер пишет в это поле "собачки", но кнопку серч не жмет, а, допустим жмет совсем другую кнопку, которая сабмитит форму, в итоге поиск таки выполняется по собачкам

в чем смысл этой второй безымянной кнопки, если,  как это следует из вышесказанного, с необходимой функцией неплохо справляется кнопка Search?

Comment: @DreamChild
Смысл другой кнопки может быть любым, главное, что при этом произойдет постбек с новыми параметрами поиска, хоть юзер и не выполнял непосредственно новый поиск. 

Я вышел из положения добавлением хиденфилдов, в которые только по кнопке серч копируются значения из инпутов. Другого варианта для меня нет из-за особенности архитекруры. Интересно, как эту тривиальную задачу решить более элегантно (хотя вебформовскиттй постбек на каждый чих вряд ли можно назвать так).